# Visual Studio Intellisense Icons available for download?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, icons, intellisense

Hi I was wondering if the icons used in Visual Studio 2010/2012's Intellisense menu, to distinguish between Methods and Fields etc, were available for download somewhere?

[image]

They would be useful as placeholders for my current application I am developing.

Comment: Ignoring the legal issues that would entail, you could always just screen capture them.

Comment: Thought I'd check if they were available for download first. I was hoping they'd be in the image pack that comes with visual studio but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are publicly available in the Visual Studio 2008 SDK under the following path:

> VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Source\CSharp\LanguageService\Resources\completionset.bmp

I do not know what license the images are distributed under, as I have only used them as part of extensions for Visual Studio itself.

Edit: The images were distributed with the SDKs for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008, but are no longer included in the SDKs for Visual Studio 2010 or 2012.

Comment: +1 for new knowledge! I knew about the VStudio image sets you could get with the SDKs but didn't even think the intellisense images would be a part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Avalon Edit is open source and there may be images from that you can use:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit

The images are the property of Microsoft and as such should not be used, I'm sure a quick google will point you in the direction of suitable images for use.

Answer (score 0):

### Visual Studio 2012 (and later)

For VS 2012 and later, you can download the icons from Microsoft's [Visual Studio Image Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825).

### Visual Studio 2010 (and earlier)

According to their [docs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17794.visual-studio-how-to-get-high-quality-icons-using-image-library.aspx), earlier versions were bundled with Visual Studio, so you can be find them locally if you have VS installed:

**Visual Studio 2005**

...\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\VS2005ImageLibrary\VS2005ImageLibrary.zip

**Visual Studio 2008**

...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\1033\VS2008ImageLibrary.zip

**Visual Studio 2010**

...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip